# Simple function not passing through the variable correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make this function:

```
autoFn();

function autoFn(){
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log('another second') }, 1000);
  setTimeout(autoFn, 1000);
}
```

Pass in a variable rather than writing 1000 twice, as follows:

```
autoFn(1000);

function autoFn(n){
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log('another second') }, n);
  setTimeout(autoFn, n);
}
```

But the above is not working correctly. After 1000ms, it just runs about a million times. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here, and how to fix it? It should, after 1000ms (1 second), just run again but wait another second until it logs 'another second' to the console.

Any advice here would be much appreciated. Thanks for any help here.

Comment: because `n` is not defined the second time it is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` is undefined in the second loop since you never pass it in. You need to supply it.

```js
function autoFn(n){
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log('another second', new Date()) }, n);
  setTimeout(autoFn, n, n);
  // setTimeout(function () {autoFn(n); }, n);
}

autoFn(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter to the recursive function call:

```
function autoFn(n){
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log('another second') }, n);
  setTimeout(() => autoFn(n), n);
}
```